# How to fetch a Variable from the graph in the session?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to inspect the filters of convolutional layers. To do this I am trying to fetch the variables during the last step of the session.

Here is a simplified version of my model:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():

    # Placeholders
    ...

    # Variables.
    conv1_w = tf.Variable(..., name='conv1_w')
    ...

    optimizer = ...
    accuracy = ...

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
    ...
    acc, c1 = session.run([accuracy, conv1_w], feed_dict=feed_test)
```

I get the following exception

```
Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x137890710> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("conv1_w:0", shape=(5, 5, 1, 16), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)
```

However, if I apply an op, I can fetch the resulting tensor without the error:

```
    c1_op = tf.mul(conv1_w,1.0)
    optimizer = ...
    accuracy = ...
```

Does Tensorflow not allow to fetch Variables?

Comment: shouldn't it be acc, conv_val = session.run([accuracy, conv1_w], feed_dict=feed_test)

Comment: It was a typo. I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

It might be somewhat confusing that the variable name and the "name" parameter are both conv1_w

Aside from that it seems like it isn't actually being used at all in your computation graph.  Meaning there's no data being pushed through it or not being used.

Quick simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

conv1 = tf.Variable(1)

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(conv1)
```

result is 1

As a side note: it's better to use tf.get_variable() instead of tf.Variable()

Comment: Hi, I have tried using an interactive session before with the same result. There was a typo in my question regarding the number of tensor fetched vs. the number of variables returned.

Comment: Can you put up more of your code or link to it? Otherwise it should work like my quick example.  Session is no different from InteractiveSession in this case.